# How do you seed models with HABTM relationships to other seeded models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on my first Rails(3) App, and looking to seed a bunch of data.

The issue I'm having is that I want to seed some models that have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with other models I've just seeded.  I'm doing what seems right, but I'm not getting the results I'm expecting.

I have an Asana model (simplified):

```
class Asana < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :therapeutic_foci
end
```

and the TherapeuticFocus model:

```
class TherapeuticFocus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :asanas
end
```

In my db/seeds.rb, I create some TherapeuticFoci:

```
tf = TherapeuticFocus.create([
  {:name => 'Anxiety'},
  {:name => 'Asthma'},
  {:name => 'Fatigue'},
  {:name => 'Flat Feet'},
  {:name => 'Headache'},
  {:name => 'High Blood Pressure'},
  {:name => 'Stress'} ])
```

Then create an Asana:

```
asanaCreate = Asana.create!([
  { :english_name => 'Mountain Pose', 
    :traditional_name => 'Tadasana', 
    :pronunciation => 'TadaSANA', 
    :deck_set => 'Basic', 
    :type => 'Standing', 
    :therapeutic_foci => TherapeuticFocus.where("name in ('Stress','Flat Feet')")}
])
```

The result is that the TherapeuticFocus models are created, the Asana is created, but it doesn't create the relationships to the TherapeuticFocus models.  The resulting array is empty.

If I run

```
TherapeuticFocus.where("name in ('Stress','Flat Feet')")
```

in the rails console, I get the expected two records:

```
irb(main):010:0> TherapeuticFocus.where("name in ('Stress','Flat Feet')")
=> [#<TherapeuticFocus id: 6, name: "Flat Feet", description: nil, created_at: "2010-10-11     01:48:02", updated_at: "2010-10-11 01:48:02">, 
    #<TherapeuticFocus id: 19, name: "Stress",     description: nil, created_at: "2010-10-11 01:48:02", updated_at: "2010-10-11 01:48:02">]
```

So, how does one do this?

Or, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

POST ANSWER:

I had already added the inflection:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'focus', 'foci'
end
```

My migration for the join tables looks like:

```
create_table :asanas_therapeutic_foci, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :asana, :therapeutic_focus
end
```

I'll try changing this to t.belongs_to instead of t.references and see if that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you register the pluralization for “focus”? It is not defined by default, so you will need to define it (usually in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`):

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'focus', 'foci'
end
```

You also need to make sure your migration has defined the correct join table for the HABTM association. Here is the pertinent part of the “up” migration that I used:

```
    create_table :asanas do |t|
      t.string :english_name
      t.string :traditional_name
      t.string :pronunciation
      t.string :deck_set
      t.string :type
    end
    create_table :therapeutic_foci do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
    create_table :asanas_therapeutic_foci, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :asana
      t.belongs_to :therapeutic_focus
    end
```

I used the models as you quoted.

With those bits in place, I was able to load your seed definitions.

Comment: Aha, I figured it out - I realized I can watch the development.log during a rake db:setup, and saw that my issue stemmed from the attribute ":therapeutic_foci" not being mass-assignable.  Fixing that, it all works.  Thanks!